# Referencing the same variable across two different classes

Tags: php, reference

```
<?php

class Foo{
    public $basket;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->basket = 1;
    }

    public function getBasket(){
        return $this->basket;
    }
}

class Bar{
    public function __construct(&$basket)
    {
        $basket++;
    }
}

$newFoo = new Foo();
$newBar = new Bar($newFoo->getBasket());

echo $newFoo->getBasket();

?>
```

I am hoping to initialise the `$basket` value in one class and manipulate the same variable via another class. Unfortunately, I keep getting the "Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in " error message.

Question: How can I change the code to make this happen? Thank you.

Comment: I would not do it this way as anything can modify the basket contents and that is not easy to maintain. I would have a separate class called Basket. Now, give Foo and Bar the same instance of the basket and they can add to it as required - but access is controlled. [demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/619687). imo, rather more easy to test, debug and add new features.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Good point, and I like what you did there. I am working towards an MVC online shopping platform. The intention of this question is to figure out how to share an object (model representation of the order) between different pages of PHP. This is a separate question which I will probably ask in the near future.

Comment: [Clearer demonstration as eval.in](https://eval.in/619689) - tidied the echoes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$newBar = new Bar($newFoo->getBasket());
```

To

```
$basket = $newFoo->getBasket();
$newBar = new Bar($basket);
```

The first way doesn't work because PHP doesn't have any variable with which to hold the value you're passing to `new Bar()`  As a consequence, nothing can be passed by reference.

The second way works because the `$basket` var is a fixed reference in memory, so it can be passed by reference to `new Bar()`

You asked in comments:

> have changed my code to yours. echo $newFoo->getBasket(); produces 1
>   (I was hoping for 2).

`1` is produced because each call to `getBasket()` gives you a fresh *copy* of the class variable.  The `$basket` that I passed to `new Bar()` equals 2, but that's not what you're echoing.

If you want the result of `getBasket()` and the variable `$basket` to refer to the same reference in memory, you need to make two changes:

**1** Change the function declaration to:

```
public function &getBasket()
```

**2** Change how you store the function result to:

```
$basket = &$newFoo->getBasket();
```

Now your echo will return `2` because you would have a unique basket reference throughout your code

[See the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)

Comment: Hi BeetleJuice, have changed my code to yours above. `echo $newFoo->getBasket();` produces `1` (I was hoping for `2`). What can I do to make that possible?

Comment: You were looking for the incrementation of `$basket` variable of `Foo` which is wrong actually you need to call function of `Bar` in order to get that your code actually works or not @taylorswiftfan

Comment: @taylorswiftfan You're bringing up an issue different from the original (which was about the error you were getting). If My code solves that issue, please select and upvote. As for your last comment, I've expanded my answer. Take another look.

Comment: Cheers for that. Apologies for the ambiguity of the intention in the question.